# when post a var contains "." then the "." changed to "_"

Tags: php

for example,in page1 I sended :

```
test.info ：1;
```

then in page2:

```
echo $_REQUEST['test.info'];
echo $_REQUEST['test_info'];
```

first one is null ,second is 1 
it changed to test_info

I just don't know the reason why the $key changed .

Comment: That's a documented behaviour...

Comment: Yeah, that's normal. The easiest workaround is not to use dots in variable names

Comment: http://php.net/variables.external

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's from the old days of php, when post, get etc. variables were turned into regular global variables. But as these have the limitation that they cannot contain dots, dots were turned into `_`

`$test.info` - invalid variable name

`$test_info` - valid

Comment: `It's from the old days of php ... ` nice answer. didn't had this in mind... :)